# Invalid token from split or input method

Tags: python

I'm currently constructing a little python script and for some reason, I'm receiving an invalid token after I input my value.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def main():
    frankOceanRelease()

def frankOceanRelease():
    info = str(input('Enter the date in which Frank will drop his album (MM/DD/YYYY):')).split("/")
    if info[1] == "13" and info[0] == "11":
        return('Let\'s hope he doesn\'t flake')
    elif info[2] == "3005":
        return('This might happen, but no guarantee')
    else:
        return('Nah man, this album ain\'t out yet!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error:

```
File "./frankOceanRelease.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
File "./frankOceanRelease.py", line 4, in main
    frankOceanRelease()
File "./frankOceanRelease.py", line 7, in frankOceanRelease
    info = input('Enter the date in which Frank will drop his album (MM DD YYYY):').split()
File "<string>", line 1
    08 07 2016
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: File "./frankOceanRelease.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()



File "./frankOceanRelease.py", line 4, in main
    frankOceanRelease()
 



File "./frankOceanRelease.py", line 7, in frankOceanRelease
    info = input('Enter the date in which Frank will drop his album (MM DD YYYY):').split('/')
  File "<string>", line 1
    08 07 2016
     ^

Comment: edit your question and post that directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Python 2, then entering the items with `input` separated by `/` (i.e. `'MM/DD/YYYY)'`) will perform multiple integer divisions. You will almost always get a `0` since the year will be far larger than the two others.

On the other hand, entering without the separator will raise the error you see since that input cannot be evaluated.

What you want is `raw_input`:

```
>>> info = raw_input('Enter the date in which Frank will drop his album (MM/DD/YYYY):').split("/")
Enter the date in which Frank will drop his album (MM/DD/YYYY):11/06/2016
>>> info
['11', '06', '2016']
```

Comment: This was problem! Thank you so much! I thought I was on Python 3.4, but I guess not! I'll upgrade it soon